# .htaccess redirects from html to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have moved a site from htm to Wordpress. I'm having issues with the redirects. They resolve to the 'old url' and a 404 inside the 'post' area. I have tried rewrite and redirect with no difference in results - Code shows both variations tried

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Redirect 301 rules here
RewriteRule ^/Costa-Rica-Real-Estate\.htm$ http://www.sitename.com/costa-rica-property/ [L,R=301,NC] 
RewriteRule ^/costa-rica-videos\.htm$ http://sitename.com/costa-rica-videos/ [L,R=301,NC] 
redirect 301 /image-viewer.htm http://sitename.com/san-ramon-costa-rica-property-gallery/
redirect 301 /about.htm http://sitename.com/about/
#End redirect rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the leading slashes from the regex of your rules and *not* use mod_alias (the `Redirect` directive).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Redirect 301 rules here
RewriteRule ^Costa-Rica-Real-Estate\.htm$ http://www.sitename.com/costa-rica-property/ [L,R=301,NC] 
RewriteRule ^costa-rica-videos\.htm$ http://sitename.com/costa-rica-videos/ [L,R=301,NC] 
RewriteRule ^image-viewer\.htm$ http://sitename.com/san-ramon-costa-rica-property-gallery/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^about\.htm$ http://sitename.com/about/ [L,R=301]
#End redirect rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The first reason is the leading slash is stripped from the URI before the rules are applied when the rules are in an htaccess file, so your rules would never match. The second reason is that mod_alias and mod_rewrite both get applied to the requests so they'll end up interferring with each other.

Comment: Thanks for that Jon - Still no change to the browser. I've copied your code

e.g. [link]http://ranchosilencio.com/How-To-Buy-Real-Estate-In-Costa-Rica.htm[/link]

    RewriteRule ^How-To-Buy-Real-Estate-In-Costa-Rica.htm$ http://ranchosilencio.com/how-to-buy-real-estate-in-costa-rica/  [L,R=301]

Comment: Got further - The code works on a Hostgator site but not on a GoDaddy site.

Thanks for your help Jon